# How does to get a byte array of updated via DocumentFormat.OpenXml word document?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to get a C# method that will update `.docx` file and return a byte array of updated file. I'm using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` for `.docx` files handling. The byte array of the original (non-updated) `.docx` file must be the method's input parameter. It is important not to save files or temporary files to drive. For this reason, I created the below method, but as I can see, my method returns the original byte array, not the updated byte array.

```
public static byte[] SearchAndReplaceByteArray(byte[] docByteArray)
        {
            MemoryStream docStream = (MemoryStream)StreamHendler.ByteArrayToStream(docByteArray);
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docStream, true))
            {
                string docText = null;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                {
                    docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                Regex regexText = new Regex("OriginalText");
                docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "UpdatedText");

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    sw.Write(docText);
                }
                
                docStream.Position = 0;
                byte[] updatedDocByteArray = StreamHendler.StreamToByteArray(docStream);

                
                return updatedDocByteArray;
            }

        }
```

Please, help me to solve the task.

Here are two methods that I'm using in method presented above:

```
        public static Stream ByteArrayToStream(byte[] inputByteArray)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
            return stream;
        }

        public static byte[] StreamToByteArray(Stream inputStream)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                inputStream.CopyTo(memStream);
                return memStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```